I updated MacOS and all the 20 odd Application Icons from my Dock Disappeared - Like the Dock Reset
There were about 20 or so shortcuts to my apps on my Dock and they've all gone, seemingly replaced by all the generic Apple ones like notes and tv etc. What happened? How do I restore without manually re-adding? Also, if I re-add them I have to also re-enter passwords and usernames again etc, whereas before they were all saved. What happened here?

What OS versions did you update from and to? Does anything remain from your previous setup? It could be that you've got a clean new user account. You should be able to restore your settings from your backup.

Did you by chance/accident create a new user account during the update?

Yeah, it feels like new user account, as stuff like tap to click was defaulted. The user remains the same though. I'm running Sonoma 14.5. I'd previously installed this update, but later restart resulted in this situation.
